# fundamental group of a union of circle and disc

Tags: algebraic-topology

let X be a topological space, defined by $$X = \{(x,y)|x,y \in \Bbb R, \space x^2+y^2=1\}\space\cup\space\{(x,y)|x,y\in\Bbb R, \space (x-2)^2+y^2\le 1\}$$ ($X$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$). $\space$ note that $X$ is path connected.

find the fundamental group of $X$.

I don't know how to solve this problem, and I will be happy if some one can give me a hint, or write the solution.

thank you very much.

Comment: The important fact to use is the two sets meet only at (1,0).

Comment: how does this fact help me?

Comment: The disc is contractible to the common point. The fundamental group is the same as that of the circle.

Comment: so the answer is $Z_2$?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant $Z$